# Numba jit and Scipy

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, artificial-intelligence, curve-fitting, numba

I have found a few posts on the subject here, but most of them did not have a useful answer.

I have a 3D `NumPy` dataset `[images number, x, y]` in which the probability that the pixel belongs to a class is stored as a float (0-1). I would like to correct the wrong segmented pixels (with high performance).

The probabilities are part of a movie in which objects are moving from right to left and possibly back again. The basic idea is that I fit the pixels with a Gaussian function or comparable function and look at around 15-30 images ( [i-15 : i+15 ,x, y] ). It is very probable that if the previous 5 pixels and the following 5 pixels are classified in this class, this pixel also belongs to this class.

To illustrate my problem I add a sample code, the results were calculated without the usage of `numba`:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import exp
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit
def fit(size_of_array, outputAI, correct_output):
    x = range(size_of_array[0])
    for i in range(size_of_array[1]):
        for k in range(size_of_array[2]):
            args, cov = curve_fit(gaus, x, outputAI[:, i, k])
            correct_output[2, i, k] = gaus(2, *args)
    return correct_output

@jit
def gaus(x, a, x0, sigma):
    return a*exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # output_AI = [imageNr, x, y] example 5, 2, 2
    # At position [2][1][1] is the error, the pixels before and after were classified to the class but not this pixel.
    # The objects do not move in such a speed, so the probability should be corrected.
    outputAI = np.array([[[0.1, 0], [0, 0]], [[0.8, 0.3], [0, 0.2]], [[1, 0.1], [0, 0.2]],
                         [[0.1, 0.3], [0, 0.2]], [[0.8, 0.3], [0, 0.2]]])
    correct_output = np.zeros(outputAI.shape)

    # I correct now in this example only all pixels in image 3, in the code a loop runs over the whole 3D array and
    # corrects every image and every pixel separately
    size_of_array = outputAI.shape
    
    correct_output = fit(size_of_array, outputAI, correct_output)
    # numba error: Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "fit" failed 
    # type inference due to: Untyped global name 'curve_fit': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'> 
    
    print(correct_output[2])
    # [[9.88432346e-01 2.10068763e-01]
    # [6.02428922e-20 2.07921125e-01]]
    # The wrong pixel at position [0][0] was corrected from 0.2 to almost 1, the others are still not assigned
    # to the class.
```

Unfortunately `numba` does NOT work. I always get the following error:

```
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "fit" failed type inference due to: Untyped global name 'curve_fit': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>
```

** ------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**Update 04.08.2020**

Currently I have this solution for my problem in mind. But I am open for further suggestions.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import exp
import numpy as np
import time


def fit_without_scipy(input):
    x = range(input.size)
    x0 = outputAI[i].argmax()
    a = input.max()
    var = (input - input.mean())**2
    return a * np.exp(-(x - x0) ** 2 / (2 * var.mean()))


def fit(input):
    x = range(len(input))
    try:
        args, cov = curve_fit(gaus, x, outputAI[i])
        return gaus(x, *args)
    except:
        return input


def gaus(x, a, x0, sigma):
    return a * exp(-(x - x0) ** 2 / (2 * sigma ** 2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    nr = 31
    N = 100000
    x = np.linspace(0, 30, nr)
    outputAI = np.zeros((N, nr))
    correct_output = outputAI.copy()
    correct_output_numba = outputAI.copy()
    perfekt_result = outputAI.copy()
    for i in range(N):
        perfekt_result[i] = gaus(x, np.random.random(), np.random.randint(-N, 2*N), np.random.random() * np.random.randint(0, 100))
        outputAI[i] = perfekt_result[i] + np.random.normal(0, 0.5, nr)

    start = time.time()
    for i in range(N):
        correct_output[i] = fit(outputAI[i])
    print("Time with scipy: " + str(time.time() - start))

    start = time.time()
    for i in range(N):
        correct_output_numba[i] = fit_without_scipy(outputAI[i])
    print("Time without scipy: " + str(time.time() - start))

    for i in range(N):
        correct_output[i] = abs(correct_output[i] - perfekt_result[i])
        correct_output_numba[i] = abs(correct_output_numba[i] - perfekt_result[i])

    print("Mean deviation with scipy: " + str(correct_output.mean()))
    print("Mean deviation without scipy: " + str(correct_output_numba.mean()))
```

Output `[with nr = 31 and N = 100000]`:

```
Time with scipy: 193.27853846549988 secs
Time without scipy: 2.782526969909668 secs
Mean deviation with scipy: 0.03508043754489116
Mean deviation without scipy: 0.0419951370808896
```

In the next step I would try to speed up the code even more with numba. Currently this does not work because of the argmax function.

Comment: `scipy.optimize` functions generally take a user provided function, and do some sort of iteration on its inputs, minimizing or fit values.  They may use their own compiled code or standard libraries.  But as a rule they won't work with the `numba` no-object mode.  Compiling your `fit` function won't make `numba` compile `curve_fit`.  Doing `njit` to your `gaus` makes sense, but don't expect the same from `fit`.

Comment: Sry, what should I change in my code or do you think it doesn't work with numba and I have to look for an alternative?

Comment: Is that actually an error, or just a warning?  If a warning, the `jit` might still work, but with a modest speedup.

Comment: It seems to be an error.

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Answer (score 6):

Curve_fit eventually calls into either least_squares (pure python) or leastsq (C extension). You have three options:

- figure out how to make numba-jitted code talk to a C extension which powers leastsq
- extract relevant parts of least_squares and numba.jit them
- implement the LowLevelCallable support for least_squares or minimize.

None of these is easy. OTOH all of these would be interesting to a wider audience if successful.

Comment: Thank you very much for the 3 suggestions, even if they are not the best answers I could come up with. But I am still hoping for another answer that offers an easier solution.

Comment: Yes, all these are rather major projects.

Comment: I think so too, but I think that someone has already solved something like my problem.